# How to know if service worker was updated in gatsby-plugin-offline

Tags: javascript, reactjs, service-worker, gatsby

I've installed [gatsby-plugin-offline](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/tree/master/packages/gatsby-plugin-offline), It works fine, but I want to listen for sw update event so I can notify user that new version of app is available.

Prior to this I used [offline-plugin](https://github.com/NekR/offline-plugin) Which I speculate is behinde gatsby's plugin? They have doc explaining how to achieve what I want here: https://github.com/NekR/offline-plugin/blob/master/docs/updates.md but I can't figure out how to get these events via gatsby, any suggestions guys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently `gatsby-plugin-offline` is a wrapper around [sw-precache](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/sw-precache), and doesn't provide any direct hooks into much beyond the caching settings shown in the config options. It looks like there are a few ways around this via sw-precache, so it might be worth working on a PR or feature request over on the gatsby issues page.

Comment: I don't if it was possible as of you wrote your answer. But it is now possible.

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for exactly the same answer.

There is an event you can hook into called "onServiceWorkerUpdateFound".
Just create (if you don't have already) a `gatsby-browser.js` file and do something like this.

**gatsby-browser.js**

```
exports.onServiceWorkerUpdateFound = () => {
    // do something
};
```

I created a `<div>` that shows a "new version available" message with an onClick event that reloads the page (this then will activate the new service worker).

More Information: [Gatsby Browser APIs](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/browser-apis/)